# How to create custom link type like Storybord

Tags: tfs, hyperlink

In TFS 2012, a product backlog has a stroybord link, which is a path to files in shared server. Now I need to create a work item type with a link to file path link similar to storyboard. So I tried the following ways.

1. Extend Linkscontrol
   It was very difficult with no enough information and not recommended by MS.
2. Create a link similar to storyboard
   To my surprise, it was impossible to export link type definition of Storyboard.
   When I use exportlinktype command, TFS tells me Storyboard does not exist.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: have you managed to find any info about the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Custom Link Types can be created using the XML convention and uploaded to the TFS server using the following command:

> witadmin importlinktype /collection:CollectionURL /f:FileName

This is what an export of link types for a collection looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<LinkTypes>
  <LinkType ReferenceName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Affects" ForwardName="Affects" ReverseName="Affected By" Topology="Dependency" />
  <LinkType ReferenceName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy" ForwardName="Tested By" ReverseName="Tests" Topology="Dependency" />
  <LinkType ReferenceName="Microsoft.VSTS.TestCase.SharedStepReferencedBy" ForwardName="Test Case" ReverseName="Shared Steps" Topology="Dependency" />
  <LinkType ReferenceName="System.LinkTypes.Dependency" ForwardName="Successor"ReverseName="Predecessor" Topology="Dependency" />
  <LinkType ReferenceName="System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy" ForwardName="Child" ReverseName="Parent" Topology="Tree" />
  <LinkType ReferenceName="System.LinkTypes.Related" ForwardName="Related" ReverseName="Related" Topology="Network" />
</LinkTypes>
```

Reference: [MSDN: Customizing link types using witadmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273716%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Point is that there is no link type of storyboard. Storyboard is hidden behind and its extension is almost impossible.